# Как запретить реддирект для некоторых страниц

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, redirect

Добрый день. Такой вопрос можно ли запретить реддирект для некоторых страниц, все равно каким способом, php, javascript или .htaccess. Что то не могу в сети такого найти. Спасибо.

Comment: Проверяйте реферала. После редиректа поле "реферал" содержит сайт - который сделал редирект, на это поле и ставьте условие.

Comment: распиши более подробно  пожалуйста, какие страницы не должны отдавать 301 какие должны , как распознать одни от других, больше информации  богу информации..